# Multidimensional Integration in Python

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

I want to integrate a simple functionf(r1,r2) = d/|r2-r1|. Where r1 = (x1,y1,d) and r2 = (x2,y2,0). But the following takes for ever:

```
import sympy as sp

antenna_h = 0.05 #m 
antenna_w = 0.05 #m
bb_h = 1 #m
bb_w = 1 #m
d = 0.30 #m

xa,ya,xb,yb = sp.symbols('xa,ya,xb,yb')
Aeff = sp.integrate(d/((xa-xb)**2+(ya-yb)**2+d**2)**0.5,
                    (xa,(-antenna_w/2,+antenna_w/2)),
                    (ya,(-antenna_h/2,+antenna_h/2)),
                    (xb,(-bb_w/2,+bb_w/2)),
                    (yb,(-bb_h/2,+bb_h/2)))
print(Aeff)
```

Some one an idea how to get the integration done in a reasonable time?

Comment: From the `sympy` tag, I presume you are looking for a symbolic solution to this but would an approximated sum work ?

Comment: Avoid using floating point numbers for powers. If you use `sqrt((xa-xb)**2+(ya-yb)**2+d**2)` instead of `((xa-xb)**2+(ya-yb)**2+d**2)**0.5` SymPy can compute one of the integrals right away (but then chokes on the next one).